# Angular Expected 2 arguments but got 3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm providing this function for my angular animation. It has 2 arguments but the error is saying that I'm providing 3.

```js
startAnimation() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    const synergy16 = new bofAnimate('synergy-16', {
      type: 'oneByOne',
      duration: 900
    }, function(synergyLogo16: any) {
      logoAppearsBeforeItDraws(synergyLogo16, "synergy-16");
    });
  }, 4000);
}
```

Error

> expected 2 arguments but got 3. function logoAppearsbeforeItDraws(arg1: any, arg2: any): any

> expected 2 arguments bot got 3 (parementer) synergyLogo16: any

I am providing 2 arguments so I'm very confused on these errors, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The function `bofAnimate` is expecting 2 arguments, but you're providing 3. The function `bofAnimate` is called with the arguments `'synergy-16'`, `{type: 'oneByOne', duration: 900 }`, and a callback function.

The callback function you're providing as the third argument to `bofAnimate` is not expected based on the error message. You should check the definition of `bofAnimate` to see what arguments it expects.

Comment: that fixed that error however im unable to call the function later in the code due to this error now. Unexpected token. A constuctor, method,accesor, or property was expected.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help out without more context. Maybe create a new question if you can't find an answer.